# Rest with audio as multipart / buffer

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, audio, streaming

I have big sized mp3 files in my server, I need to consume those audio files on a web page

My approach was to break those files in chunks in the server and consume with rest those chunks depending on where the user needs to listen ( imagine a YouTube video scrolling bar) through a REST spring boot multipart api

I am really unsure of my approach as I think there should be a better technology than this just to start buffering the audio file from server

Any idea ?